# Change date format on Fetch mysql

Tags: php, mysql

For Example.

In the field "date_account_created" It stores a date with format **"2011-12-21 03:34:21"**

And that's ok...

But when i fetch this in PHP i need to:

1) Do not print the clock "03:34:21"

2) I want to Print DD-MM-YYYY instead of YYYY-MM-DD

Is this thing possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't change it as it's being fetched, but rather when querying it by using [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(date_account_created, '%d-%m-%Y') AS date_account_created
FROM table...
```

That is, unless you will be needing to use the date in PHP in multiple different formats. In that case, it may be simpler to select it as a UNIX timestamp, which can be natively manipulated in PHP without needing to convert via `strtotime()`.  This is recommended only if you intend to use the date in multiple different formats in your PHP application code. If you're using only one format, it's simpler to use `DATE_FORMAT()` in the query as above.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_account_created) AS date_account_created FROM table...
```

Then manipulate in php:

```
// Already fetched into $date_account_created
echo date("d-m-Y", $date_account_created);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reformat date in your sql fetch request

> DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS new_date

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%W %M %Y');
        -> 'Sunday October 2009'
```